# Reopen Silverlight AutoCompleteBox popup without reloading suggestions from webservice

Tags: c#, silverlight, autocomplete

I have an AutoCompleteBox binded to an ObservableCollection ItemsSource which I filter on my own by querying entities from a domainservice.
I used the scenario of populating from a webservice call from the blog of Jeff Wilcox, by setting the PopulatingEventArgs.Cancel to True, and when my collection is ready, I call PopulateComplete() on the ACB.

My goal is to reopen the dropdown on mouseover (or click) but without reloading again all the data from the web. I found a question on stackoverflow where the answer was to set IsDropDownOpen to True. But in this case, the ACB population starts again, and another call goes to the webservice.

Of course, when the user starts typing, the filtering should be done again.
(for ex. you type "ric" and the box suggests "rice" and "ricin", you select rice, but you change your mind and want to select another one from the same collection, lets say "ricin". In this case you already have the suggestions containing "ric" in memory, no need to load them again..)

I found an alternative way in which instead of setting IsDropDownOpen, I just simply call the PopulateComplete() method. This does exactly the same thing that I want, but with a little fail: after my ACB loses focus, the dropdown is not opened again on mouseover liek it should. Even when I click back into the acb textbox.

So is there a fix for this, or does someone know why the PopulateComplete() only reopens the dropdown when the ACB has focus for the first time? Or this was only my luck that calling this method reopened the dropdown and the IsDropDownOpen property should be used instead (afaik this would be only possible with some flags indicating that its a fake populating event triggered by my mouseover and after PopulatingEventArgs.Cancel i should call immediately PopulateComplete. but i dont get it, if this may work (haven't tried yet), why not when calling simply the PopulateComplete)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I tried the IsDropDownOpen with a testing bit, and almost worked:

```
private void FoodBox_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        //FoodBox.PopulateComplete();  not working after acb loses focus...            

        testbit = true;
        FoodBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;        
    }
```

Here's the overloaded Populating method (no need for setting ItemsSource explicit because its bound to an ObservableCollection):

```
public void FoodBox_Populating(object sender, PopulatingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;            
        if (!testbit)
        {
            VM.LoadFoodSuggestions(FoodBox.SearchText);
        }
        else
        {
            testbit = false;
            FoodBox.PopulateComplete();
        } 
    }
```

This works good so far, execpt that the search does not start because when (for the first time) you mouseover and select the acb, it sets the testbit to true.
So I added another event handler that takes care of setting the testbit to false every time the user inputs text on the keyboard, ensuring that the suggestions are regenerated/reloaded after SearchText is modified by the user, but not when you select an item from the dropdown:

```
private void FoodBox_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        testbit = false;
    }
```

I still don't know why calling PopulateComplete() isn't enough without setting the IsDropDownOpen to Ture, and setting that to true, also delays the dropdown opening approximately with the time specified in the MinimumPopulateDelay, but at least it gives me the functionality I wanted. (Maybe digging into the source of acb would answer this mistery)

Maybe this functionality implemented in the basic acb would be helpful in a future release of the control.